# Vanilla JavaScript get value from select box?

Tags: javascript, forms

This is an old script and my modification isn't working.

```
var x=parent.frames[0].document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
for(a=0; a < x.length; a++){
```

I need to add support for select boxes so I did this..

```
var x=parent.frames[0].document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
var y=parent.frames[0].document.getElementsByTagName("select");
x = x+y;
for(a=0; a < x.length; a++){
```

After the `for` we have this.

```
if(misc.length == 0){
    misc = misc + x[a].name + ':' + x[a].value + ':' + x[a].checked;
} else {
    misc = misc + "~cmd~" + x[a].name + ':' + x[a].value + ':' + x[a].checked;
}
```

Does anyone know how to get this going so the select values are returned also in the array?

Comment: Not sure if adding two arrays with + operator is allowed. You can use the concat method instead. Also, what is the error you get with above code? More details please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<select>` elements must be read differently. You need to loop over its options. Here you are some sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><title></title>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
function fetchValues(){
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
    var output = "";
    for(var i=0, len=s.length; i<len; i++){
        output += s[i].name + ":\n";
        for(var j=0, lenj=s[i].options.length; j<lenj; j++){
            output += "\t- " 
                   + s[i].options[j].value 
                   + " (" + s[i].options[j].text + "): " 
                   + (s[i].options[j].selected ? 'Yes' : 'No') 
                   + "\n";
        }
    }
    alert(output);
}
//--></script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="get">
    <select name="single-value">
        <option value="s1">First single value</option>
        <option value="s2">Second single value</option>
        <option value="s3" selected="selected">Third single value</option>
        <option value="s4">Fourth single value</option>
    </select>
    <select name="multiple-values" multiple="multiple" size="5">
        <option value="m1">First multiple value</option>
        <option value="m2" selected="selected">Second multiple value</option>
        <option value="m3">Third multiple value</option>
        <option value="m4" selected="selected">Fourth multiple value</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" onclick="fetchValues()" value="Fetch values">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I suggest you use these ideas to write a function that takes a `<select>` node as argument and returns an array.

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByTagName returns a HtmlCollection and unfortunately we can't just use `x.concat(y)` to return a new combined array.

You can just create a new array and then loop through x and y and push the value on it.

```
var z = new Array();

for (var i=0; i < x.length; i++) {
    z.push(x[i]);
}

for (var j=0; j < y.length; j++) {
    z.push(y[j]);
}

var misc="";
// Loop through z and do whatever we want
for (var k=0; k < z.length; z++) {
    if(misc.length == 0){
        misc = misc + z[k].name + ':' + z[k].value + ':' + z[k].checked;
    } else {
        misc = misc + "~cmd~" + z[k].name + ':' + z[k].value + ':' + z[k].checked;
    }
}
```